# Java: counting occurrence in java array

Tags: java

Task(Not homework):  Write a program that reads an unspecified number of scores and determines how many scores are above or equal to the average and how many scores are below the average
Issue:  I keep getting array index out of bound error while trying to count the occurrence of the input scores.  Will appreciate your guidance on how to improve the occurrence output.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class AnalyseScore {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the number of students:");
      int studentnumber = input.nextInt();
      //creat  array
      int [] scores =new int[studentnumber];
      int sum =0;


     System.out.println("Enter the student scores:");
     for(int i =0; i<scores.length;i++){
         scores[i]= input.nextInt(); 
        }
     //calculate the  sum  and  the average

     double average;
     for(int i =0; i<scores.length;i++){
        sum +=scores[i];
        }
        average = sum/studentnumber;     

    System.out.println("The  average is:" + (int)(average*100)/100.0);
        int belowavg=0;
        int aboveavg=0;
        for(int i=0;i<scores.length;i++){
        if (scores[i]>average)
            aboveavg++;
        else
            belowavg++;
        }
    System.out.println(" the  number of  scores bove the  average:"+ aboveavg);
    System.out.println("the  number of  scores below  average:" + belowavg);
     int [] count= new int[scores.length];
     for( int i=0;i<scores.length;i++){
        count[scores[i]]++;

    System.out.println(scores[i] + "occured" + count[i]);
}
  }
  }
```

Comment: `count[scores[i]]++;` worries me. What happens if `scores[i] = 99999999`?

Comment: What line is generating the exception? (@Mshnik - That can't be a serious concern. Nobody has time to input 100,000,000 numbers.)

Comment: `average = sum/studentnumber` be weary of integer division

Comment: @Ted Hopp Not if there are 9999999 scores, but if an individual score has the value 9999999.

Comment: If you are using Java 8 you can optimize the sum of the int array with

int sum = IntStream.of(scores).sum();

Comment: @Mshnik - Right you are. That's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int [] count= new int[scores.length];
 for( int i=0;i<scores.length;i++){
    count[scores[i]]++;
```

Here the index for `count` is bounded by `scores[i]`, which may be way larger than `scores.length`.

If `scores` is known to be bounded, you could calculate the max value and allocate enough size; otherwise, use `Map<Integer, Integer>` such as `TreeMap<Integer, Integer>` or `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` may be better.

If you refuse to use `Map`, I would suggest sort-and-count `scores`.

```
if (scores.length > 0) {
    Arrays.sort(scores);
    int count = 1;
    int prevscore = scores[0];
    for (int i = 1; i <scores.length; ++i) { 
        if (scores[i] == prevscore) {
             ++count;
        } else {
             System.out.println(prevscore + " occured " + count);
             count = 1;
             prevscore = scores[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(prevscore + " occured " + count);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the amendments. Actually I am  on  a  self-study  program  and I  am yet to learn   the  use of  map, Hashmap and  treemap.I  know  will  time  I would  get there. But is  there  no  way to  restructure  the  code  without the  use of  maps and  still get the  desired  output

Comment: @pumpin26 Added sort-and-count approach to avoid maps

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good up until the last step. You're trying to count the number of occurrences of each score, but that requires the length of the `count` array to be the maximum score (which would be very inefficient space wise). As it is, you aren't making `count` large enough, hence your error. Consider using a `HashMap<Integer,Integer>` instead of an array for count. The keys in this map would be the scores, and the value is the number of occurrences:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<scores.length;i++){
   if(! count.containsKey(scores[i]) count.put(scores[i], 1); //New score, has been seen once
   else count.put(scores[i], count.get(scores[i]) + 1); //Already seen score, inc count.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

count's length is equal to score's length. You are getting an error because the highest score is higher than score's length.